# How to convert okhttp3 ResponseBody multiple types?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using TMDb API and it returns two different HttpException errorBody type.

One is a proper ApiStatus model which contains status code and message in json.
Other is an error array in json.

So I need to check these two types and convert them to proper Error models.(ApiStatus and Error pojos)

Here is what I'm trying to do to handle two cases:

```
public abstract class DisposableSingleObserverWrapper<T> extends DisposableSingleObserver<T> {
    public abstract void onSuccess(T t);

    public abstract void onFail(Throwable e);

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
        if (e instanceof HttpException) {
            ResponseBody body = ((HttpException) e).response().errorBody();

            try {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http:/fakeapi/")
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                //New status code handling in tmdb api
                Converter<ResponseBody, ApiStatus> errorConverter2 = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(ApiStatus.class, new Annotation[0]);
                ApiStatus apiStatus = errorConverter2.convert(body);
                if (apiStatus != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(apiStatus.getStatusMessage())) {
                    onFail(new Throwable(apiStatus.getStatusMessage()));
                }
                else {
                    //Old case of handling status codes in tmdb api
                    Converter<ResponseBody, Error> errorConverter = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Error.class, new Annotation[0]);
                    Error error = errorConverter.convert(body);
                    if (error != null & error.getErrorList()!=null && error.getErrorList().size()>0) {
                        onFail(new Throwable(error.getErrorList().get(0)));
                    }
                    else{
                        onFail(new Throwable(((HttpException) e).response().code() + " - " + ((HttpException) e).response().message()));
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                onFail(new Throwable(((HttpException) e).response().code() + " - " + ((HttpException) e).response().message()));
            }
        } else {
            onFail(e);
        }
    }

    public class Error {
        @SerializedName("errors")
        public ArrayList<String> errorList;

        public ArrayList<String> getErrorList() {
            return errorList;
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of work doesn't work as intended because ResponseBody is consumed in first trial of converting and in second case it has no data. My question is how can I clone ResponseBody or what kind of approach should I follow to deal with this situation?

Comment: You need to have an interceptor to make a clone of your response.that you can use to pass it to your second case.

Comment: You can read it from http://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html and cast exception what evet you like in _RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory_ *asRetrofitException* method

Comment: Thanks for the article, @engincancan. It didn't solve the converting responsebody twice problem. Apperantly, I need to save string of it and then parse with gson for both cases thx to haditok from gdgistanbul slack community. However, this error handling approach looks much better. Although it isn't using Rxjava 2, I found the converted one from the same author so I'll try to combine it with my case and see how it goes. Thx!

Comment: We are using it with Rx2 without a problem. I was came up with the idea to setting it up to the variable however it is a naive approach to do it. It is better to use Adapter to it like you are using Gson to parse String to your POJOs.